# If $(x_n)$ is ud mod $1$ and $(y_n)$ satisfies $\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac 1N \sum_{n=1}^N |y_n|=0$ then $(x_n+y_n)$ is ud mod $1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

> If $(x_n)$ is ud mod $1$ and $(y_n)$ satisfies
> $$\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac 1N \sum_{n=1}^N |y_n|=0$$
> then $(x_n+y_n)$ is ud mod $1$.

Since this comes as an exercise after the first two sections of the first chapter of [Uniform Distribution of Sequences](https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/%7Ejosefdick/preprints/KuipersNied_book.pdf), I guess we need to use the Weyl criterion. So, we want to show that
$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N e^{2\pi ih(x_n+y_n)}=0$$
for all non-zero integers $h$.

We can note that $\sum_{n=1}^N |y_n|$ is a monotone sequence, and hence it either converges or diverges to $\infty$. If the series converges, then $\lim y_n=0$ which completes the proof (by Lemma $1.1$). But, I don't know what to do if the sum diverges to $\infty$. I need some help with it.

Comment: @Ѕᴀᴀᴅ what's wrong with the tag? Why are you removing it? Please add an explanation.

Comment: Please don't unilaterally creating tags without community consensus. I've flagged this question for mods' attention.

Comment: @Ѕᴀᴀᴅ is that a rule here? Then, I'm sorry, I wasn't aware of that... But still, ud mod 1 is a fairly old topic which I believe deserves a tag in MSE. Anyways, let's see what others think about it.

Comment: @SayanDutta If you wish to discuss creations of new tags, then Mathematics Meta is the place. There is a tag called [tagging] in math.meta.stackexchange.com that would be applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's indeed a reasonable approach to use Weyl's criterion. Simply note that $$\big| e^{2i\pi h(x_n+y_n)} - e^{2i\pi hx_n}\big| = \big|e^{2i\pi h y_n} - 1\big| = \big|e^{i\pi h y_n} - e^{-i\pi h y_n}\big| = 2|\sin(\pi h y_n)| \le 2\pi h |y_n|.$$

Hence $$\Big|\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N e^{2i\pi h(x_n+y_n)} - \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N e^{2i\pi h x_n} \Big| \le 2\pi h \frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{n=1}^N |y_n|$$

Since $\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N e^{2i\pi h x_n} \underset{N \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$ and $\frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{n=1}^N |y_n| \underset{N \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$, we conclude that $\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N e^{2i\pi h(x_n+y_n)} \underset{N \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$.

Comment: Beautiful! (+1)